# mongodb cluster upgrade config servers fails

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm trying to create a mongodb cluster with 3 machines by following this link : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/ . I have downloaded mongodb 2.6.4 to all machines and started config servers with this command :

```
 mongod --configsvr --dbpath /home/sshusr/mongodb/data/configdb/
```

and I'm trying to start a mongos instance to upgrade config servers to v5 because it tells me to do that. So I run this command

```
mongos --upgrade --configdb 10.122.123.64:27019,10.122.123.65:27019,10.122.123.66:27019
```

but it gives me this

```
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] MongoS version 2.6.4 starting: pid=50066 port=27017 64-bit host=tesla (--help for usage)
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] db version v2.6.4
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-09-26T17:07:55.629+0300 [mongosMain] options: { sharding: { configDB: "10.122.123.64:27019,10.122.123.65:27019,10.122.123.66:27019" }, upgrade: true }
2014-09-26T17:07:55.633+0300 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [10.122.123.64:27019]
2014-09-26T17:07:55.633+0300 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [10.122.123.65:27019]
2014-09-26T17:07:55.633+0300 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [10.122.123.66:27019]
2014-09-26T17:07:55.718+0300 [mongosMain] scoped connection to 10.122.123.64:27019,10.122.123.65:27019,10.122.123.66:27019 not being returned to the pool
2014-09-26T17:08:06.770+0300 [mongosMain] waited 11s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-09-26T17:08:17.816+0300 [mongosMain] waited 22s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-09-26T17:08:28.863+0300 [mongosMain] waited 33s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-09-26T17:08:39.909+0300 [mongosMain] waited 44s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
....
```

what am I missing here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a question either for http://dba.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com , since stackoverflow.com is dedicated to programming questions. When posting on one of the appropriate platforms (I suggest http://dba.stackexchange.com), please clarify wether you are upgrading an old cluster or install a new one, because your post is a bit contradictory regarding that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  thanks, I will post this question to an appropriate platform with more clarification

Comment: @AdamComerford: thank you for the information. Flagged it accordingly.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - my information was incorrect (so will delete), it's actually part of the close vote flow (default migration path) rather than something that requires moderator intervention, so apologies if I led anyone astray.  Correct thing to do is vote to close and suggest the correct destination StackExchange site

Comment: @AdamComerford: Thanks for the update, will keep that in mind when I am able to vote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

I executed the command with verbose and saw that there was a time/date difference between servers. I have assigned an ntp server for each server and problem was solved.